# Tokyo Ghoul √A Episode 9 - Yoshimura's Monologue

Tags: tokyo-ghoul

Not an Anime fan but I've found this one because an artist used some quotes from Tokyo Ghoul. I want to find this monologue in Japanese. Can you help me?

This is the monologue: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4o1GTVPrexA
This is the song: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BqVe_agO9IE (Scarlxrd - King, Scar 1:52)
This is a related Reddit post: https://www.reddit.com/r/scarlxrd/comments/hawx6n/the_japanese_audio_sample_from_king_scar_tokyo/

Comment: Hi, can you clarify by "find this monologue in Japanese"? There's already the monologue in Japanese in the first video, and you know the timestamp of when it's used in the song in the second video. Did you mean to transliterate it?

Comment: I've already shared a version with English subtitles. But I want to see original Japanese sentences and not with Latin alphabet if it's possible. I can understand what's he saying because of subtitles. I want to see the original Japanese text.@AkiTanaka

Comment: Is the manga source (if available) for the text allowed? Or does it have to be a video of the same scene? Or even if anyone transcribing the monologue directly from the video?

Comment: Transcribe would be enough. I just want a text so I can translate, read, practice on it and finally sing along with the song completely :) After that, I'll probably start watching Tokyo Ghould too :)